# Inner select order by mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, where-clause, dense-rank

I need to do order by UserId in this inner select (so before this last WHERE clause is considered) but since I get error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions...

I cant do it that way. Is there some other way I can order by UserId and DENSE_RANK() by JobId as is now?

Most of UserId values are NULL and when dense_ranked by JobId I need to sort those JobIds so that first are ones where UserId != NULL

```
SELECT *, @RecordCount as RecordCount
FROM
(
    SELECT JobId, UserId, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY JobId) AS Rnk
    FROM #ListOfJobs
) t
WHERE Rnk between (@pn - 1) * @ps + 1 and @pn * @ps
```

Comment: How about `ORDER BY UserId` instead of JobId in OVER clause?

Comment: Since I can have one UserId for many different JobIds I cant use it that way because I need it dense ranked and sorted by JobIds... But first those where UserId isnt NULL...

Comment: For pn (page num) = 1 ps (pagesize) = 10 I get 23 entries where first 13 jobs with UserId != null and other 10 are JobIds with UserId = null but on other page I get first 6 JobsId where UserId = null (so its 13+6=19 now which are all jobs with userid = null) with again rest JobsIds where userid=null as it should be... but those 6 on pn 2 should be with first 13 on pn 1.. If you understand me :D

Answer (score 0):

What's about using CTE for obtaining the dense_rank and then sorting by UserId in the derived result set:

```
;WITH cte AS (

    SELECT JobId, UserId, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY JobId) AS Rnk
    FROM #ListOfJobs
    WHERE Rnk between (@pn - 1) * @ps + 1 and @pn * @ps 
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY UserId DESC, Rnk
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using order by for both JobID and UserId.

```
  SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *, @RecordCount as RecordCount
   FROM
     (
   SELECT JobId, UserId, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY JobId) AS Rnk
    FROM #ListOfJobs ORDER BY UserId
    ) t
   WHERE Rnk between (@pn - 1) * @ps + 1 and @pn * @ps
```

Comment: I have edited my query, just try this with latest changes. I have added Top 100 Percent in the query. I think, now it will work it out.

Comment: Still getting error for using Order in subquery... Only if I place that TOP 100 in this inner select then it works but again wrong result although I thought it would work this way...

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to first list all the entries with where `UserId` is specified and then those where it is not, you could just modify your `DENSE_RANK` expression like this:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN UserId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, JobId)
```

That effectively sorts by two columns, of which the first one is a flag that indicates whether `UserId` is null or not and the second one is `JobId`. Rows where the flag is 0 will be assigned lower `Rnk` values than rows where the flag is 1.